# creating a frequency dictionary from an existing dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, count, python-datetime

I have a dictionary called playlist with entries in the form of:

```
{datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 4, 20, 2): ('Wagon Wheel', 'Darius Rucker'), 
datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 4, 19, 59): ('Remember You Young', 'Thomas Rhett'), 
datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 4, 19, 55): ('Long Hot Summer', 'Keith Urban')}
```

I want to iterate through this dictionary to construct a new dictionary song_count with the name of each song as a key and its count/frequency as the values. Here's what I have for code so far.

```
song_count = {}
for song in playlist:
    if playlist[song] in song_count:
        song_count[playlist[song]].append(song)
    else:
        song_count[playlist_[song]]=[song]
print(song_count)
```

However, this fails to separate the song from the artist in the key and does also not create counts as values.

The new dictionary should look like:

```
{'Wagon Wheel-Darius Rucker': 1, 
'Remember You Young-Thomas Rhett': 7, 
'Long Hot Summer-Keith Urban': 1, … }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this adaptation of your code:

```
# Initialise new dictionary
song_count = dict()

# For each entry in the playlist dict
for song in playlist.values():
    # Convert the tuple to song-artist string
    song_name = '-'.join(song)

    # If already in the dictionary, add 1 to the count
    if song_name in song_count:
        song_count[song_name] += 1

    # Otherwise set the count to 1
    else:
        song_count[song_name] = 1
print(song_count)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Wagon Wheel-Darius Rucker': 1, 'Remember You Young-Thomas Rhett': 1, 'Long Hot Summer-Keith Urban': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `collections.Counter`:

```
import collections
import datetime

d = {datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 4, 20, 2): ('Wagon Wheel', 'Darius Rucker'), 
     datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 4, 19, 59): ('Remember You Young', 'Thomas Rhett'), 
     datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 4, 19, 55): ('Long Hot Summer', 'Keith Urban')}
songs = ['-'.join(song) for song in d.values()]
c = collections.Counter(songs)
```

output is:

```
Counter({'Wagon Wheel-Darius Rucker': 1, 'Remember You Young-Thomas Rhett': 1, 'Long Hot Summer-Keith Urban': 1})
```